# I'm having difficulty in passing update query to database in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using update function to update my data but this query is not working for me. I am using implode function and getting my form data in an array. I don't know what am i missing?

```
 public function update($table_name,$table_cols,$table_vals,$user_id)
        {



            $string="UPDATE users  set   " . implode("," , $table_cols). " VALUES" .
             implode("," , $table_vals);
             $string .=" where id=" . $user_id;

            $stmnt=$this->conn->prepare($string);
            $result=$stmnt->execute();

            if($result) {
                echo "successfull";
            }


        }
```

Comment: You're most likely missing the parenthesis surrounding your column names and values, as well a space after `VALUES` and quotes around each of the values. But the best way to check is to echo/log your `$string`, examine it, and try to run it directly into a database. However, this is an extremely buggy way of creating an update function.

Comment: `UPDATE` doesn use `VALUES`. The syntax is `SET col1 = value1, col2 = value2, ...`

Answer (score -2):

you tried to use `VALUES` syntax, which is for `insert` not for `update`.
Take a look for more: https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-update